# Accessing Files and Images in a "built project"

Tags: java, file, build

I have created a space invaders game that I want to be able to play from an executable JAR file.

When I clean and build the project, the files that I use to access high scores and high levels are not accessible, and the image files I use for the background and ships are not accessible.

How can I change the input so that it is able to find the files?

```
backGround = new ImageIcon("resources/images/background.jpg");
highScoreFile = new File("resources/files/highscore.txt");
highLevelFile = new File("resources/files/highlevel.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use a class loader resource to read your files:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();    
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

Comment: when i do that it gives me a null pointer exception... do i have my files in the right location?